# pivot a group data summary

Tags: sql, t-sql, apache-spark-sql, analytics, mathematica-8

I have the following table in sql and I need to use data summary

| DEPARMENT | JOB | QUARTER | ITEM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Training | null | Q1 | 8 |
| Support | null | Q2 | 4 |
| Support | null | Q3 | 2 |
| Research and Development | null | Q4 | 2 |
| Support | Account Coordinator | Q1 | 8 |
| Training | Account Coordinator | Q2 | 5 |
| Engineering | Account Coordinator | Q3 | 1 |
| Support | Account Coordinator | Q4 | 2 |
| Services | Account Executive | Q1 | 5 |
| Support | Account Executive | Q2 | 4 |
| Support | Account Executive | Q3 | 5 |
| Support | Account Executive | Q4 | 7 |
| Human Resources | Account Representative I | Q1 | 1 |
| Services | Account Representative III | N/I | 1 |
| Research and Development | Account Representative III | Q1 | 2 |
| Business Development | Account Representative III | Q2 | 1 |
| Support | Account Representative III | Q4 | 2 |
| Training | Account Representative IV | Q1 | 4 |
| Support | Account Representative IV | Q2 | 3 |
| Support | Account Representative IV | Q4 | 5 |
| Training | Accountant I | Q1 | 6 |
| Product Management | Accountant I | Q2 | 1 |
| Marketing | Accountant I | Q3 | 5 |

I have tried to use but it does not bring me the desired results

```sql
SELECT DEPARMENT
    , MAX(JOB)
    , COUNT(QUARTER)
FROM TESTHIRED_EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY DEPARMENT
    , JOB
    , QUARTER
```

To obtain a table like this

| DEPARMENT | JOB | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Support | Account Coordinator | 30 | 0 | 10 | 5 |
| Services | Account Representative III | 0 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| Research and Development | Account Representative III |  | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| Business Development | Account Representative III | 10 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Support | Account Representative III | 23 | 2 | 1 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

This documentation should explain a bit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-pivot. It also has solutions without a pivot with the use of, in your case, `count(qarter) filter(where quarter = 'Q1') as Q1`